# Elements in array ignored by indexOf

Tags: javascript

I have the following function. Everything works, except for the 'if' statement as noted in the comment.

```
function markRow(e) {
    var row = e.currentTarget.value ;

    var id, rid, field, color, ico ;

    rid = markedrows.indexOf(row) ;
    if (rid != -1) {
        markedrows.splice(rid, 1) ;
        ico = ICO_FOLDER + ICO_PLUS ;
        color = COLOR_UNMARKED ;
    } else {
        markedrows.push(row) ;
        ico = ICO_FOLDER + ICO_MINUS ;
        color = COLOR_MARKED ;
    }

    e.currentTarget.src = ico ;

    for (var col = 1 ; col <= current.cols() ; col++) {
        alert(col) ;
        alert(markedcols.toString()) ;
        // This 'if' doesn't seem to work
        if (markedcols.indexOf(col) == -1) {
            // This part is ALWAYS executed even when the column is in markedcols
            // I get no error messages in firefox
            id = "r" + row + "c" + col ;
            field = document.getElementById(id) ;
            field.style.background = color ;
        }
    }

    markedrows.sort(numericalorder) ;
}
```

The `alert`s are there for debugging and they clearly show that `markedcols` does contain the column as it should, but the `indexOf` doesn't seem to catch it.

As I understand it all modern browsers and in particular firefox now supports `indexOf` on arrays, so I'm completely lost. I've gone through the code's logic over and over and it *should* work. It just doesn't.

Comment: Does `markedcols` contain strings instead of numbers perhaps? They show up similar in `alert`.

Comment: @pimvdb Ah, that's it. I thought javascript did conversions between primitive types automatically, but apparently not in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the fact that:

```
["1"].indexOf(1) === -1; // true
```

so you may want `.indexOf(col.toString())`.

Although `"1" == 1`, `.indexOf` seems to do a `===`-like comparison. [V8 does, at least.](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/array.js#1210)

**Edit:** The [specs](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.14) state that `===` should be used indeed:

> Let `same` be the result of applying the **Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm** to `searchElement` and `elementK`.
>
> If `same` is `true`, return `k`.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I'd ever have figured that out myself. Problem solved.